# Assigning a variable through the end of the array

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, split, delimiter

I am trying to figure out if there is a way to assign my last variable (`var4`) to the rest of my array after `[2]`.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string var1;
    string var2;
    string var3;
    string var4;

    string readContents;
    using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(@"File.txt"))
    {
        readContents = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        string[] lines = readContents.Split('\r');
        foreach (string s in lines)
        {
            string[] lines2 = s.Split('\t');
            var1 = lines2[0];
            var2 = lines2[1];
            var3 = lines2[2];
            var4 = lines2[3];
            Console.WriteLine("Var1: {0}\nVar2: {1}\nVar3: {2}\nVar4: {3}", var1, var2, var3, var4);
            Console.ReadLine();    
        }
    }
}
```

Each variable is separated by a tab, so the split works. But after IP Address, I am hoping to get the whole error message (which includes tabs, and runs to the end of the array) within `var4`.

File contents:

```
2015-04-19 00:00:00  HostName.ErrorLevel    IP Address  "Error Message"
2015-04-19 00:00:00  HostName.ErrorLevel    IP Address  "Error Message"
2015-04-19 00:00:01  HostName.ErrorLevel    IP Address  "Error Message"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can try something like

```
var4 = String.Join(" ", lines2.Skip(3));
```

This will concatenate all entries in `lines2` array having index > 2 (i.e. skips three first elements) using space as separator.

Answer (score 3):

`Split` has an optional additional parameter of an `int count`.  If you pass it a number it won't split the string into more than that many elements, putting the remainder of the string into the last element.